# How to improve this query and check for nullable objects inside linq-expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

The current project i'm working on consists of an Application-, BLL- and data-layer. Currently the Application has an direct reference to the datalayer. Since I want to apply OO correctly I want to break the relation between the Application- and datalayer by adding Business objects in the the BLL-layer. Currently very basic with only the same properties as the entity object, but I want to extend them later on with their own constructor en CRUD-methods.

This work partially, the query below gets me a list of projects with their portfolio items inside. However, the portfolioitems **can** contain a maximum of three images, contained in a object. I esspecially say, **can** because they can be NULL.
The NULL-able object are currently giving me the problem, ideally I want to check for an image *inside* the query, but I don't know how (if it's even possible).

This is the query;

```
List<BLL.Objects.Portfolio> listOfPortfolios = (from pf in _portfolioService.AsQueryable() //Generic service returning IQueryable
    where !pf.IsDeleted && pf.IsPublished
    orderby pf.PublishStart
    select new BLL.Objects.Portfolio //Object in business layer
   {
       Id = pf.Id,
       IsDeleted = pf.IsDeleted,
       IsPublished = pf.IsPublished,
       LastModified = pf.LastModified,
       Name = pf.Name,
       Projects =
            (from prj in pf.Projects //prj = object in datalayer
             where !prj.IsDeleted && prj.IsPublished
             orderby prj.PublishStart descending
             select new BLL.Objects.Project //Object in business layer
            {
                Id = prj.Id, 
                Title = prj.Title,
                Description = prj.Description, 
                EndDate = prj.EndDate, 
                IsDeleted = prj.IsDeleted, 
                IsPublished = prj.IsPublished, 
                LastModified = prj.LastModified,
                PublishEnd = prj.PublishEnd,
                SmallImage = new Image //This line causes the error. Image is a object in the business layer
                 {
                     Extension = prj.SmallImage.Extension, //prj.smallimage is an entity in my datalayer
                     FileContent = new ImageContent
                       {
                           Id = prj.SmallImage.FileContent.Id, 
                           Content = prj.SmallImage.FileContent.Content
                       }, 
                     Filename = prj.SmallImage.Filename, 
                     Height = prj.SmallImage.Height, 
                     Id = prj.SmallImage.Id, 
                     IsDeleted = prj.SmallImage.IsDeleted, 
                     IsPublished = prj.SmallImage.IsPublished, 
                     LastModified = prj.SmallImage.LastModified, 
                     MimeType = prj.SmallImage.MimeType, 
                     PublishEnd = prj.SmallImage.PublishEnd,
                     PublishStart = prj.SmallImage.PublishStart
                 }
            }).ToList(),

              //MediumImage = new Image { Extension = prj.MediumImage.Extension, FileContent = new ImageContent { Id = prj.MediumImage.FileContent.Id, Content = prj.MediumImage.FileContent.Content }, Filename = prj.MediumImage.Filename, Height = prj.MediumImage.Height, Id = prj.MediumImage.Id, IsDeleted = prj.MediumImage.IsDeleted, IsPublished = prj.MediumImage.IsPublished, LastModified = prj.MediumImage.LastModified, MimeType = prj.MediumImage.MimeType, PublishEnd = prj.MediumImage.PublishEnd }

       //pf.Projects.Where(
       //    p => !p.IsDeleted && p.IsPublished)
       //         .OrderByDescending(p => p.PublishStart)
       //         .ToList(),
       PublishEnd = pf.PublishEnd,
       PublishStart = pf.PublishStart,
       SystemName = pf.SystemName
   }).ToList();
```

The error i'm getting when i add the line with the 'SmallImage' to the query is the following;

```
"The cast to value type 'System.Guid' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."
```

I know this is because the list of projects with this particular portfolio contains 4 items with only one of them having an SmallImage. The two questions I have with this are;

1. How can I check for an object being null inside a linq-query to prevent this problem?
2. Can this very large query be simplified?

Comment: Just a thought, but it looks to me as though you could set SmallImage to prj.SmallImage instead of manually doing property assignment. If prj.SmallImage is null, ANY of those property assignments could fail and are likely to be the cause of the error you are seeing (but most likely on the Id fields themselves).

Comment: @Joe, Thanks for your response. The problem is that prj.SmallImage refers to an Entity in my datalayer. And I want to convert it to an Object in my business layer, that why i've chosen this approach.

Answer (score 1):

just add a null check:

```
            SmallImage =  prj.SmallImage == null 
                        ? null 
                        : new Image 
             {
                 Extension = prj.SmallImage.Extension, //prj.smallimage is an entity in my datalayer
                 FileContent = new ImageContent
                   {
                       Id = prj.SmallImage.FileContent.Id, 
                       Content = prj.SmallImage.FileContent.Content
                   }, 
                 Filename = prj.SmallImage.Filename, 
                 Height = prj.SmallImage.Height, 
                 Id = prj.SmallImage.Id, 
                 IsDeleted = prj.SmallImage.IsDeleted, 
                 IsPublished = prj.SmallImage.IsPublished, 
                 LastModified = prj.SmallImage.LastModified, 
                 MimeType = prj.SmallImage.MimeType, 
                 PublishEnd = prj.SmallImage.PublishEnd,
                 PublishStart = prj.SmallImage.PublishStart
             }
```

Comment: Sounds very obvious! However, now i'm getting this error: "Unable to create a null constant value of type 'BLL.Objects.Image'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context." Any ideas?